Microsoft DNS listening on a high-numbered TCP port
In addition to port 53, the Microsoft DNS service also listens on a single high TCP port. This port changes every time the service starts (since it is a high port). What is this port used for?

Note: This is a TCP port in the LISTENING state. It is not one of the many UDP ports in the port pool/socket pool that Microsoft DNS server maintains.

Here is a PowerShell command that displays the listening ports for the DNS service so you can see what I mean. The listeners on port 61267 are the ones I am asking about.
PS C:\Users\vboxuser> Get-NetTCPConnection |
>>   Where-Object {
>>     $_.OwningProcess -eq $(Get-Process -Name "dns").Id `
>>         -and $_.State -eq "Listen"
>> }

LocalAddress                LocalPort RemoteAddress  RemotePort State   AppliedSetting
------------                --------- -------------  ---------- -----   --------------
::                          61267     ::             0          Listen
fe80::1033:c6e3:a7d1:2b1%4  53        ::             0          Listen
::1                         53        ::             0          Listen
0.0.0.0                     61267     0.0.0.0        0          Listen
127.0.0.1                   53        0.0.0.0        0          Listen
10.0.2.201                  53        0.0.0.0        0          Listen

